# How can I word wrap this list item in Firefox 11?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have html like:

```
<fieldset>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="test"> This paragraph contains a very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. The long word will break and wrap to the next line.  </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</fieldset>​
```

and Css like

```
fieldset
{
  max-width : 1em;
  width: 1em;
  border:1px solid #000000;
}
li
{
  max-width:inherit;
  width:inherit;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}​
```

How it looks in Chrome(Desired Outcome):
[image: Good]

How it looks in Firefox(Problematic outcome):
[image: Bad]

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GuSPE/2/)
How can I achieve the word-wrapping displayed via Chrome in Firefox, by just adjusting CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me.

```
fieldset
{
  max-width : 1em;
  width: 1em;
  border:1px solid #000000;
}
li
{
  max-width:1em;
  width:1em;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}​
```

Either do not use inherit on li or do a inherit on both its parent div and ul

```
fieldset
{
  max-width : 1em;
  width: 1em;
  border:1px solid #000000;
}

fieldset > div{
width:inherit;
}
fieldset > div > ul{
width:inherit;
}

li
{
  max-width:inherit;
  width:inherit;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the width for the li as well, as with FF it does not accept the 1em inherit width. If you specify `width:1em;` in the li CSS, you will get the desired result in FF. Perhaps if you do not want to make every li that size, make it a class.

See updated [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GuSPE/3/)